# Magento 2 - new vendor package installed - how to call it?

Tags: magento2

I have installed via composer the Array2XML package (composer require openlss/lib-array2xml). The package has installed correctly, but my question is how do I now use this in my module (observer)?

I have tried:

```
<?php 
use Openlss\Array2XML;
use Openlss\LSS\Array2XML;
use Openlss\Array2XML\Array2XML;
use Openlss\lib-array2xml\LSS\Array2XML; // this fails due to the hyphen
?>
```

(and just about every other combination I can think of!)

Each one of these fails with a class not found error.

This is how the package has installed:

[image]

This is the composer file that was generated:

```
{
     "name":                "openlss/lib-array2xml"
    ,"homepage":            "http://openlss.org"
    ,"description":         "Array2XML conversion library credit to lalit.org"
    ,"license":             "Apache-2.0"
    ,"type":                "library"
    ,"keywords": [
         "array"
        ,"xml"
        ,"xml conversion"
        ,"array conversion"
    ]
    ,"authors": [
         {
             "name":        "Bryan Tong"
            ,"email":       "contact@nullivex.com"
            ,"homepage":    "http://bryantong.com"
        }
        ,{
             "name":        "Tony Butler"
            ,"email":       "spudz76@gmail.com"
            ,"homepage":    "http://openlss.org"
        }
    ]
    ,"require": {
        "php":  ">=5.3.2"
    }
    ,"autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "LSS": ""
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried clearing cache, setup:upgrade, deleting var/generation etc but nothing has worked.
Using Magento 2.1.6

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Try use LSS\Array2XML;

Comment: That's it! :) Thank you. Please add as an answer and I'll accept. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `use LSS\Array2XML;`

You have defined the root folder as "LSS" in your composer.json file

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "LSS": ""
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.